# Vue Router - update or clear query

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I am writing a ui filter which should output all active filters as a query parameters

```
const query = this.$route.query
if (!query[type]) {
  return this.$router.push({ query: { ...query, [type]: value } }) // works fine!
}

if (Array.isArray(query[type])) { 
// some changes    
} 

this.$router.replace({ query: { ...query } })
```

But it doesn't work! If before the parameter was a string, and then mutated into an array (for example: `query: '1'` to `query: [1, 2]` then the router ignores the update. Or if all filters have cleared and I need to clear the address bar.

Comment: You can clear the address-bar by setting `query = {};`

Comment: I found that the issue happens on old version of vue-router, such as 2.1.2. I can not reproduce on the latest version. Is it possible to upgrade your version of vue-router or try the work-arounds mentioned on [$router.push({query: this.myarray}) not updating the URL](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/1182).